# Any mathematician known to be good at pure mathematics but bad at an applied mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, mathematicians

There are mathematicians who are not good at taking math exam, say Hermit. Is there any mathematician known to be good at only pure mathematics, whose ability may not be that well at applied mathematics? By ability in applied math I mean the ability to do mathematical modeling.

Comment: ...most mathematicians?

Comment: Euler was good at lots of applied math, but here is an account where he failed: http://www.sps.ch/en/articles/physics-anecdotes/euler-and-the-fiasco-at-sanssouci-2/

Comment: Newton and the cat door? You got to be very bad at applied math for this one: https://io9.gizmodo.com/the-legend-of-isaac-newtons-most-foolish-and-cat-frie-511737218

Comment: @imranfat, Haha!

Comment: @Srini, your source says he did not :-) It says he was blamed of the failure although he warned about it.

Comment: I was wondering the same haha! @RolazaroAzeveires, Srini

Comment: Bertrand 'Thus mathematics may be defined as the the subject in which we never know what we are talking about, not whether what we are saying is true. ' Russell may be an example.